# No converter found capable of converting from type [query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [com.name.dto.TransferTest]

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

Currently I have a query in my Repository where I'm returning 2 columns from the database.

```
@Repository
public interface HomeTransferPageRepository extends JpaRepository<TransferEntity, Integer> {
    
    @Query(value="select DISTINCT transfer_to, username from (select transfer_to, transaction_date, username from transfers_table left join registration_entity on transfers_table.transfer_to = registration_entity.id where transfer_from= :transfer_from ORDER BY transaction_date DESC LIMIT 10 )  as x", nativeQuery=true)
    public ArrayList<TransferTest> getTransferRequests(Integer transfer_from);

}
```

Now TransferTest here is my dto:

```
@Data
public class TransferTest {

    private Integer transfer_to;
    private String username;
}
```

This is my DAO

```
@Autowired
    private HomeTransferPageRepository homeTransferPageRepository;
    
    public ArrayList<TransferTest> getSentTransfers(TransferEntity entity) {
        return homeTransferPageRepository.getTransferRequests(entity.getId());
    }
```

And This is my service class:

```
@Autowired
    private SendMoneyDAOImpl daoImpl;
    private ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    
    @Override
    public ArrayList<TransferTest> getSentTransfers(TransferRequest request) {
        TransferEntity entity = modelMapper.map(request, TransferEntity.class);
        ArrayList<TransferTest> getTransfers = daoImpl.getSentTransfers(entity);
        return getTransfers;
    }
```

And this is my transferEntity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "transfers_table")
public class TransferEntity {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer Id;
    private Integer transfer_from;
    private Integer transfer_to;
    private Double transaction_amount;
    private Date transaction_date;
    
}
```

And this gives me the following error when I run it:

No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [com.name.dto.TransferTest]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For native query you have to use  Interface based Projection:

for interface-based projection modify `TransferTest` to be like this:

```
public interface TransferTest {

    Integer getTransfer_to();
    String getUsername();
}
```

and make sure also to use projection in the SQL query:

```
@Repository
public interface HomeTransferPageRepository extends JpaRepository<TransferEntity, Integer> {
    
        @Query(value="select DISTINCT transfer_to as transfer_to, username as username from (select transfer_to, transaction_date, username from transfers_table left join registration_entity on transfers_table.transfer_to = registration_entity.id where transfer_from= :transfer_from ORDER BY transaction_date DESC LIMIT 10 )  as x", nativeQuery=true)
        public ArrayList<TransferTest> getTransferRequests(Integer transfer_from);
    
    }
```

Comment: No, this still gives a ` No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [com.upyouth.dto.TransferTest]` error

Comment: @New_dev I've edited my answer, also stop the application and run mvn clean install before retesting it